# Eclipse hangs intermittently on PC without internet connection

Tags: eclipse, offline

I've encountered this problem since Eclipse 3.2, but in the newer versions the problem occurs more often.

The eclipse IDE will be unresponsive for a few seconds (up to a minute?) whenever I access certain configuration menu items or when eclipse parses an XML file which contains xmlns variables pointing to some internet URL. (eg; xmlns:rich=http://richfaces.org/rich" )

Does anyone know how to set Eclipse to operate in "offline" mode? Or to cache the internet item locally?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is to specify your own local copies of the referenced schema files. Under the Preferences, XML → XML Catalog, select **User Specified Entries** and click **Add**. Then you can add your own entry there, which could refer to a local file or even a file in your workspace.