# Offline Eclipse plugin installation never finish

Tags: eclipse, offline-mode

Trying to install typescript_ide or springsource-tool-suite on top of my eclipse installation on an offline Redhat7 never finish,
Eclipse seems stucked on "Calculating requirements and dependencies"

Logs seems to show that eclipse is trying to reach http://download.eclipse.org:

```
> Jun 21, 2017 6:43:55 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to {}->http://download.eclipse.org: Network is unreachable (connect failed)
```

Is there any way to tell eclipse to avoid any network call, 
a kind of offline mode like asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3332051/1767316) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3532a794-bb99-461e-9e32-a922f5e7a1b8/can-you-start-eclipse-with-an-offline-parameter?forum=tee)  ?

Answer (score 1):

Clear the 'contact all update sites during install to find required software' flag at the bottom of the 'Available Software' dialog displayed by 'Help > Install New Software...'

Comment: had just found ir here: https://www.dvteclipse.com/documentation/e/How_do_I_disable_Eclipse_Software_Sites.3F.html.  Thanks!